# disappear again to a completely different location

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Hawking's explanation begins with quantum mechanics, which explains
> how subatomic particles behave. In quantum studies, it's common to see
> subatomic particles like protons and electrons seemingly appear out of
> nowhere, stick around for a while and then **disappear again to a
> completely different location**.

[Source:  Live Science](https://www.livescience.com/63854-stephen-hawking-says-no-god.html)

I don't quite understand the grammar of "disappear again to a completely different location" -  if it disappears, how can you know it is in a different location? So logically, it probably means "appear again in a completely different location and then disappear". I am not sure.

What does "disappear again to a completely different location" actually mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could have been better expressed, but the writer says that the particles "*seemingly* appear out of nowhere" (they must have come from somewhere), so it's implied that they also *seem* to disappear, although they have actually just moved to another location.

Comment: I think this article illustrates the problems that popular-science writers have when attempting to explain quantum phenomena. I think it would be less misleading to say that according to some interpretations,  virtual particles start to exist and then cease to exist. They 'pop into' and pop out of' existence. They don't 'come from' anywhere, and they don't 'go' anywhere. Other interpretations call them 'mathematical fictions'. As for the 'disappearing to' usage, I can say that I disappeared upstairs, or to Paris.